# Collaborative data modelling software?

Tags: collaboration, modeling

I'm trying to find a tool where a lot of people can work on a data model collaboratively.  Embarcadero has a an ER application called ER/studio which apparently comes with a repository system that acts like typical version control software.  That sounds great except ER/studio is expensive and this is a non-profit and open source organization where we encourage members to even contribute small changes.

What's the best solution?  Either downloadable software or a web service would work.  We don't mind paying, but the cost can't go up with the number of participants...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using [Gliffy](http://www.gliffy.com/). Not perfect (can't do some simple things like evenly distribute objects in a selection), but is very easy to work and collaborate with.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a wiki? [Mediawiki](http://www.mediawiki.org) (the software that runs Wikipedia) is free.

Comment: mediawiki does not allow users to collaborate on diagrams or especially ER models easily